# Carthage not using latest version installed

Tags: carthage

I am getting this error when using `Carthage`:

```
Please update to the latest Carthage version: 0.34.0. You currently are on 0.27.0
```

But I already have 0.34.0 installed. If I do `brew info carthage` this prints:

```
carthage: stable 0.34.0 (bottled), HEAD
Decentralized dependency manager for Cocoa
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage
/usr/local/Cellar/carthage/0.34.0 (8 files, 5.2MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2020-01-09 at 09:18:31
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/carthage.rb
==> Requirements
Build: xcode ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

And if I try to upgrade `brew upgrade Carthage`:

```
Warning: Carthage 0.34.0 already installed
```

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. No matter how many times I tried to uninstall, install, or upgrade Carthage, I always had 0.34.0!

I followed some command lines from this [Answer](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2933#issuecomment-694369317). I totally doubt I had installed the package in the past but after I did this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/carthage
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/CarthageKit.framework
brew install carthage
```

I got this message:

[image]

So I tried:

```
brew upgrade carthage
```

And:

[image]

I might or not might work for you but it did for me...

Answer (score 2):

Try running `brew uninstall carthage` and then `brew install carthage` to see what happens. For me was an error with symlink, and there was instructions on how to fix the issue.